# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key' pyodbc error 42000

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, postgresql

I am running into the error when running a python script pushing data from PostgreSQL to MSSQL.

2020/09/17 09:55:26:mssql:ERROR:Something went very wrong inserting data into mssql - bailing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./my_file.py", line 40, in importToMSSQLReal
dataToInsert)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'. (156) (SQLExecute)")

Here is the line of code:

```
query = """SELECT vi.asset_id ,vi.vulnerability_id,a.last_assessed_for_vulnerabilities as "last_detected",vi.status,vi.proof::varchar(10485760),vi.key::varchar(10485760),vi.service,vi.port,vi.protocol
    FROM  public.fact_asset_vulnerability_instance vi
    INNER JOIN public.dim_asset a
    ON vi.asset_id = a.asset_id"""
```

Insert

```
def importToMSSQLReal(mssql,mssqlstring,dataToInsert):
mssql = pyodbc.connect(mssqlstring)
log = logging.getLogger('mssql')
curs = mssql.cursor()
curs.fast_executemany = True
try:
    curs.executemany(
            "INSERT INTO {table} (asset_id,vulnerability_id,last_detected,status,proof,key) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)".format(table=mscfg['table']),
            dataToInsert)
    mssql.commit()
except:
    print("bad")
    log.exception("Something went very wrong interting data into mssql - bailing")
    exit(2)
curs.close()
mssql.close()
del mssql
```

Comment: `,vi.proof::varchar(10485760),vi.key::varchar(10485760)` is not valid syntax for a T-SQL selection field list. What are you trying to do here? Pass a parameter, cast a value, ... ?

Comment: I think you need to show the INSERT statement which is failing, not the SELECT statement, which apparently is not failing.

Answer (score 0):

`Key` is a [reserved keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL Server.  You have to make sure it is between brackets:

```
SELECT 1 as [key]
```